# Anything wrong with the following code? (html/javascript/href)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, hyperlink, href

```
<html>
<title>My Web Page</title>

<form onsubmit="return redirect()">
<input id="search_form_input" type="text" name="query" />
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function redirect() {
var link = document.getElementById('link');
link.href += document.getElementById('search_form_input')
return false;
}
</script>

<body>
<p>
<a id="link" href="http://www.cnn.com/">CNN</a>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically id like the input from the form to extend itself onto the URL at CNN.com. For example, politics is entered in the form, submitted, and clicking the CNN link would bring one to CNN.com/politics. Am i going about this the right way?

Comment: why your form is in the header? it have to be in the body!

Comment: it is not in header. But it also not in body :) In general, it's quite broken markup.

Comment: Your <title> isn't in a <head> field either...
That's some pretty gross looking html.

Answer (score 3):

It's crazy what you are doing, and how you are doing it. Go for other solutions, but your problem is simple. You're attaching the whole element to the `href` string. So instead of

`link.href += document.getElementById('search_form_input')`

use

`link.href += document.getElementById('search_form_input').value`

The full result being:

```
<html>
<title>My Web Page</title>

<form onsubmit="return redirect()">
<input id="search_form_input" type="text" name="query" />
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function redirect() {
var link = document.getElementById('link');
link.href += document.getElementById('search_form_input').value
return false;
}
</script>

<body>
<p>
<a id="link" href="http://www.cnn.com/">CNN</a>
</p>
</body>
</html>​
```

Give a try to jQuery at the very least.

Comment: there is no ";" after .value and the markup is still very bad. close the <head>, put the <script> in the <head> and the <form> into the <body>.

Comment: I would also go the jQuery route, but it isn't absolutely necessary.  The main change I would make is to remove the form submission.  I'm not posting a separate answer, because this answer covers the issue.

Comment: thanks for help. I see now what i was doing incorrect and wana slap myself in the face. I would be interested in the jquery method. If anyone can provide me with a link to something I might be able to reference that would help. And one more thing, is it possible to save that search input value and keep it the same. For example with the present code browsing back and forward between links resets the form field. If you run the code you'll see what im talking about.